# Hiding Pixelation using Photo effects: "LOMO"

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, cs5, photography

I have an Image in size 20"*30". I wanted to get it printed on canvas but it is pixelated, I got some ideas that applying "LOMO" effects or Grains on the image can help avoid pixelation and image can be printed comfortably. I could not get any such solution, do we have any such solution or any other Effect too which can help for the same?

Comment: What are LOMO effects?

Comment: @Scott I assume lomography (ala Instagram filters)

Comment: As for the question, there is no 'effect' that can really hide pixelation. If there aren't enough pixels, there aren't enough pixels. You can try resizing the image in PhotoShop, and PhotoShop will attempt to smooth things out with extra pixels. That may look OK.

Comment: The original Lomo was a cheap, rather badly-made Soviet-era camera. Lomo was to cameras what Yugo was to cars, but the low quality of its shots (blur, light leaks, distortion, vignetting) made for a kitchy, artsy look if you used it right. The LOMO movement took off in the early 90s, and it's still going.

Answer (score 2):

GRAIN is used by photo manipulation softwares such as Photoshop Lightroom to mimic film grain. And it's a very good way to bring back a sense of texture and sharpness to an image suffering from NOISE. Especially if the de-noising tools are used. When well used, grain can greatly repair a noisy picture and make it a very nice one.

Used on a too-much-scaled image with pixelated effect, it only accentuate the pixellation somehow.

Photoshop CC has Intelligent Upsampling. Be sure to select "Preserve details" in the Imge size dialog.

[image: Intelligent Upsampling with Phososhop CC]